# After adding Prune filter along with KV filter - logs are not going to Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk

I am learning ELK and trying to do as a POC for my project. I am applying KV filter for the sample integration logs from my project and i could see lot of extra fields are coming as a result so i have tried to apply prune filter and white-listed certain fields. I can see the logs getting printed in the logstash server but logs are not going to elastic search. If i remove the filter it is going to the elastic search. Please advise how to further debug on this issue.

```
filter {
    kv {
            field_split => "{},?\[\]"
            transform_key => "capitalize"
            transform_value => "capitalize"
            trim_key => "\s"
            trim_value => "\s"
            include_brackets => false   
        }
    prune
    {
        whitelist_names => [ "App_version", "Correlation_id", "Env", "Flow_name", "host", "Instance_id", "log_level","log_thread", "log_timestamp", "message", "patient_id", "status_code", "type", "detail"]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "mule-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I also need two more suggestion,

I am also trying to use the grok filter in the initial logs and trying to take log level fields(time and log type) from the sample log and send the remaining logs to the KV filter. Is there any reference please share for it. This is what i have tried for it. but getting as _grokparsefailure. I have passed the msgbody to the kv filter with the source option.

```
grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"}
        overwrite => [ "msgbody" ]
    }
```

I am having message fields inside sample logs as like below. When the data goes to Kibana i can see two message field tag one is with full log and other is with correct message(highlighted). Will the mutate works for this case? Is there any way we can change the full log name as something else ??

> [2020-02-10 11:20:07.172] INFO Mule.api [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.04:
>   [main-api-test].api-main.CPU_LITE @256c5cf5:
>   [main-api-test].main-api-main/processors/0/processors/0.CPU_LITE
>   @378f34b0]: event:00000003 {app_name=main-api-main, app_version=v1,
>   env=Test, timestamp=2020-02-10T11:20:07.172Z,
>   log={correlation_id=00000003, patient_id=12345678,
>   instance_id=hospital, message=Start of System API,
>   flow_name=main-api-main}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**prune filter error**

Your `prune` filter does not have the `@timestamp` field in the `whitelist_names` list, your output is date based (`%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`), logstash needs the `@timestamp` field in the output to extract the date.

I've ran your pipeline with your sample message and it worked as expected, with the `prune` filter the message is sent to elasticsearch, but it is stored in an index named `mule-` without any datetime field.

Without the `prune` filter your message uses the time when logstash received the event as the `@timestamp`, since you do not have any date filter to change it.

If you created the index pattern for the index `mule-*` with a datetime field like `@timestamp`, you won't see on Kibana any documents on the index that doesn't have the same datetime field.

**grok error**

Your grok is wrong, you need to escape the square brackets surrounding your timestamp. Kibana has a grok debugger where you can try your patterns.

The following grok works, move your kv to run after the grok and with the `msgbody` as source.

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"}
    overwrite => [ "msgbody" ]
}
kv {
    source => "msgbody"
    field_split => "{},?\[\]"
    transform_key => "capitalize"
    transform_value => "capitalize"
    trim_key => "\s"
    trim_value => "\s"
    include_brackets => false
}
```

Just run it with output only to stdout to see the filters you need to change your `prune` filter.

**duplicated message fields**

If you put your `kv` filter after the `grok` you wouldn't have duplicated `message` fields since your `kv` is capitalizing your fields, you will end with a `message` field containing your full log, and a `Message` field containing your internal message, logstash fields are case sensitive.

However you can rename any field using the `mutate` filter.

```
mutate {
    rename => ["message", "fullLogMessage"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and for your time. I need one more suggestion on pipeline. I am trying to pick files from multiple s3 bucket and process it to the single ES. So I was going to create 4 pipeline for 4 bucket as input and output as one ES. Will all it run parallely ? Since if I give interval to check in bucket as 10min if it takes more time to process the input of first run from pipeline 1 more than 10 min s. What will happen to the pipeline 2, 3 etc? So is there any way I can run all bucket individually without any dependence on each s3 bucket.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to add the two fields present in grok filter to the output response but i was unable to add it. Can you help me on it? i have changed the name in the grok as below and added this in the add filter tag... add_field => { "loglevel" => "%{loglevel}" "log_timestamp" => "%{log_timestamp}" }   i was trying to save the timestamp/loglevel in time and string format

Comment: You should post new questions, your comments are unrelated to your original question.

Comment: Thanks.. I will post a new question for grok issue. Please help me on the new question also

Comment: I have created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190835/how-to-extract-field-from-the-grok-filter